# message( $${QMAKE_FILE_IN} ) did not print the current processing input file

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to print the current processing file using QMAKE_FILE_IN variable how to do it.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to print the variable?  Is it defined?  I searched the qmake reference (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-variable-reference.html) and didn't see that variable defined.  Although it is listed in various undocumented qmake sheets, that is no guarantee that the variable is available to you.

Comment: I am trying to create a cross compiler build file using the QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS qmake variable, In order to test it i thought of printing the values that the variable contains. The variable QMAKE_FILE_IN has been used in the example showed in the qt labs site by troll employee. http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2008/04/16/the-power-of-qmake/

Answer (score 7):

Try below message format

```
message($$QMAKE_FILE_IN)
```

you can add other text with variable as follow

```
message(qmake file in value = $$QMAKE_FILE_IN)
```

Answer (score 2):

"Messages are written out for each Makefile generated by qmake for a given project." (from the documentation), and not during make.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how to print the current processing file

Comment: Untested: You could add an echo to your command like so:      mycommand.commands = echo ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}; myprocess ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.out